# Using dplyr to cross join but only by the number preceding

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, network-programming, cross-join

I would like to turn this data frame:

```
y<- c("1","2","2","3")
n<- c("co","ny","tn","ri")
data <- data.frame(y,n)
```

into this data frame

```
y <- c(1,1,2,2,3)
n <- c("co","co","ny","tn","ri")
n2 <- c("ny","tn","ri","ri",NA)

data <- data.frame(y,n,n2)
```

I was thinking somethin along the lines of a cross join but I would need to join only by number n and n+1. This is to generate a network that would should a propagation of information over time, in this case y is equal to years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion made for a join with n+1 was along the right lines but for the output required n-1 is needed.

The original reprex has y as a character and this needs to be numeric so I would do that outside of the join, otherwise the mutate will need to be repeated as the table is joined onto itself:

```
  data <- data %>% 
    mutate(y = as.numeric(y))
```

Join the table onto itself:

```
  data %>% 
    left_join(data %>% 
                mutate(y = y - 1), 
              by = "y")
```

Comment: While the method using the tidyverse did work, I think the simplest answer was this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do this with `tidyverse` functions.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  summarise(n = list(n), 
            count = n()) %>%
  mutate(n2 = lead(n),
         n2 = map2(n2, count, ~if(length(.x)) 
                   rep(.x, length.out = max(.y, length(.x))) else NA)) %>%
  unnest(c(n2, n)) %>%
  select(-count)

#   y     n     n2   
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 1     co    ny   
#2 1     co    tn   
#3 2     ny    ri   
#4 2     tn    ri   
#5 3     ri    NA
```